# How to sort keys of dict by values?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have a dict `{'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}`.

Need to sort keys by values so that I can get a list `['b', 'c', 'a']`

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sorted_keys = sorted(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> d={'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}
>>> [i[0] for i in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])]
['b', 'c', 'a']
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import operator
lst1 = sorted(lst.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: It returns [('b', 0), ('c', 1), ('a', 2)]. Close.

Comment: Now you can loop and print the 0th index of every key value pair. So, this is a way by which you don't even lose the mapping of key and value.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way to do it.
You can use .items() to get key-value  and use sorted to sort them accordingly.

```
dictionary = sorted(dictionary.items(),key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {'a':2, 'b':0, 'c':1}
>>> sor = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> sor
[('b', 0), ('c', 1), ('a', 2)]
>>> for i in sor:
...     print i[0]
...
b  
c 
a
```