# Sort python dict by two values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I've the following dict of list

```
d = {
    'k1':['EKAD', 444.2089, 121],
    'k2':['EKADD', 559.2358, 121],
    'k3':['KADDLG', 600.2988, 122],
    'k4':['ADDLGKG', 657.3202, 123]}
```

I wish to get the keys sorted first by `value[2]` then by length of `value[0]` string and in reverse order, i.e. the output will be k2, k1, k3, k4.

Comment: Possible duplicates (in combination): [How to sort keys of dict by values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37270095/4518341), [How to sort a list with two keys but one in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37693373/4518341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted(d, key=lambda x: (d[x][2], -len(d[x][0])))
```

Explanation:

Iteration over dictionaries returns keys. So, `sorted(d, ...)` will return keys sorted by the `key` criteria

`key` lambda generates tuples that will be used for comparison in sort. Tuples are compared using first element, then second, etc. If tuple is used as a key, it will sort using the first element (`x[2]`), then second (length of the first string), etc.

To reverse order on the length, but not on the numeric value, the length is negated